# How do I read a MSSQL DateTimeOffset column in a Visual C++ application?

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++, ado, datetimeoffset

I have an Visual C++ (MFC) application using ADO to access a Microsoft SQL Server database. I'd like to start using DateTimeOffset columns but I'm getting an exception.

Here's a code snippet:

```
HRESULT hRes = pRecordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
FieldPtr fieldPtr = pRecordset->Fields->GetItem(bstrFieldName);
DataTypeEnum type = fieldPtr->Type;
_variant_t vFieldValue = fieldPtr->Value;
```

Assigning `Value` to a `_variant_t` throws `0x80020008 Bad variable type`.

`fieldPtr->Type` is 146 for DateTimeOffset fields. Understandably, as ADO 2.8 presumably pre-dates this column type, 146 isn't in `DataTypeEnum`. However, I know that I can access these fields in classic ASP, which is also ADO 2.8.

How do I access this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft provides [support for downlevel clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx#BackwardCompatibilityforDownlevelClients) by casting DateTimeOffset to a string type.

This means that where `Provider=SQLOLEDB`, DateTimeOffset will be returned as a string. (This explains why I was successfully able to access the field using classic ASP).

If you're using a more recent provider such as SQL Server Native Client 10.0 OLE DB Provider (`Provider=SQLNCLI10`), you'll need a different approach.

The simplest approach is to cast to a varchar in the SELECT statement:

```
SELECT CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS VARCHAR(34))
```

An alternative is to use `VARIANT` to access the value as a double (`dblVal`) and convert from that. For example:

```
HRESULT hRes = pRecordset.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
FieldPtr fieldPtr = pRecordset->Fields->GetItem(bstrFieldName);
VARIANT v;
VariantInit(&v);
fieldPtr->get_Value(&v);
_bstr_t bstrTime = v.bstrVal;
VariantClear(&v);
```

However, I'm not aware of a library that will convert the floating point representation to something more useable so there's some additional work to do there.